# Extracting all image links from webpage with relevant tags in a list using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

First of all, I'm very new to programming, so I seriously appreciate any advice.

I'm trying to scrape all the images from a webpage and output a list of image tags plus the image link next to the name.
The relevant tags are class="card-text-title" and class="prints-current-set-name"

This is what I have so far, the extracted raw urls, but it's the simple URLS, not the actual image urls I'd need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://scryfall.com/cubes/vintage"
response = requests.get(url)
 
data = response.text
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
 
tags = soup.find_all('a')
 
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

I can't wrap my head around what I'd need to do to get an output such as:

"ORI/Abbot of Keral Keep", "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/c/b/cb7a2770-9a20-4f52-aac4-24502f50e374.jpg?1571661132"

"CMR/Abrade", "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/d/2/d27d5b87-6dfc-4b99-822b-f6f8489ad275.jpg?1608912224"

...

and so on and so forth for the 540 images.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you want the final result to be a list of dictionaries with the image tag and image link.. corect?

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://scryfall.com/cubes/vintage"
response = requests.get(url)
 
data = response.text
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
 
tags = soup.select('#main > div.card-grid > div > * > a > div > div > img')
 
for tag in tags:
    print(f"{tag.get('alt')}   {tag.get('data-src')}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with your code is that you are selecting all the links on the page.. your going to have to be more specific to get the result you want. To fix this first select the parent div that wraps all the cards and then select the images from that.

Secondly the data is a little messy so your going to need to refine it a bit.. I think the other answer missed the fact that some of the cards use the `src` attribute while others use the `data-src` attribute for the link so your going to need an if statement to check for that.

Once that's done you should have a nice clean list of all the image names and links, see code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://scryfall.com/cubes/vintage"
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

card_grid = soup.find("div", {"class": "card-grid"})
cards = card_grid.findAll("img")

imgs = []

for card in cards:

    tag = card["alt"]
    link = card["src"] if card["src"] != "" else card["data-src"]

    imgs.append({"tag": tag, "link": link})

print(imgs)
```